# How to extract the world co-ordinates from a PCL

Tags: ros, pcl, depth-image, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently trying to extract the world co-ordinates from a pointcloud reconstructed scene. I am currently using ROS-Hydro.

I have followed these two as my reference.
http://answers.ros.org/question/98011/how-to-convert-pclpointcloud2-to-pointcloudt-in-hydro/
http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros

I am subscribing to the pointcloud message generated by the proc stereo_img_proc.

My code is something like this.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl/conversions.h> 
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <pcl/PCLPointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>

void cloud_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 pc)
{
  
pcl::PCLPointCloud2 pcl_pc;
pcl_conversions::toPCL(pc, pcl_pc);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;
pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(pcl_pc, cloud);
for(int i=0;i<cloud.height;i++)  
{   
    for(int j=0; j<cloud.height;j++)    
    {       
         BOOST_FOREACH (const pcl::PointXYZ& pt, cloud.points);

            }
    }
}
```

I want to have the depth value for every pixel and then publish it in form of a sensor_msgs::Image message.
Please guide me.

Edit:

I have made some modifications.

```
for(int j=0; j<cloud.points.size();j++)    
{               
    float x = cloud.points[j].x;
    float y = cloud.points[j].y;
    float z = cloud.points[j].z;
        
}
```

where x,y,z are the world co-ordinates as extracted from cloud. Will this work??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192489/how-to-extract-the-world-co-ordinates-from-a-pcl./) by [m1ckey](https://answers.ros.org/users/19640/m1ckey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-09-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The 'world coordinates' of a pointcloud are represented in the transform data. If your pointcloud is in the *sensor* frame, and you have a tf transform (link) available to a *map* or *world* frame, you can use the tf library to transform the pointcloud into the desired frame, which will transform the positions of the points in the pointcloud.

The image you're talking about sounds like a projection of the pointcloud down to a 2D plane, which you can do by iterating over every point in the cloud (which you're already doing) and applying some linear algebra (look into the Eigen library). To actually build the image you'll probably find OpenCV and this [conversion](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) useful, however you could build the sensor_msgs/Image [directly](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html).

EDIT: Found this [projection](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/project_inliers.php) API in PCL as well which should make it easier.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [m1ckey](https://answers.ros.org/users/19640/m1ckey/) on 2014-09-16**:
Hi,

Actually my point is I want to extract the depth or Z coordinate from a PCL and in place of the intensity value of the pixel I want to replace the same with the Z co-ordinate value.